# NAT doesn't work on Debian inside VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I have to have a computer running Linux with me but the computer is not mine (I can only use it) and I can't make a dualboot. I installed it inside a VM.

Normally the laptop is connected on a wireless network, which works perfectly with Debian inside the VM through NAT. However, the location where I'm headed does not have wireless so I'm going to have to use an "Internet stick" that is connected through USB and does not have Linux drivers.

This doesn't work with NAT. What should I do in order to get the internet working inside the VM? NAT inside VirtualBox does not support anything other than TCP and UDP, including VPN so I think I'm going to have to configure Bridging but I don't know how.

I'm using a product which I assume connects via VPN.

Comment: What type of VPN are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Another option is to create a live-boot usb, give it a cache file, and boot linux off that. It probably won't run as fast as it would inside a VM, but it would avoid a lot of the annoying VM issues.

Comment: @Goyuix I'm using one of their Mobile Connect products http://www.business.vodafone.com/site/bus/public/enuk/support/10_productsupport/laptop_connectivity/40_software/software/10_latest/p_software.jsp and I assume that it connects through a VPN.

Comment: @SaintWacko What do you mean? I could boot off of a live CD and save the sessions in a cache file on the HDD?

Comment: @andreas.vitikan - No, you can create a live USB drive, and create a file on it that acts like the hard drive for the live copy. Hang on a sec, I'll find my copy of liveusb-creator and see what they call it.

Comment: @andreas.vitikan - Ah, they just call it 'Persistent Storage'. You can find the liveusb-creator [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/). It really depends on how long you need it for, whether it would be easier to work out the bugs in the VM, or just use a live copy.

Comment: I think this "Persistent Storage" will be much better suited. I still have to go see about getting Linux drivers for the stick, but all in all it looks like a better solution. How big does the stick have to be?